# ESLint errors when running as script from package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I am able of running ESLint from the command line using:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint "src/**/*.js"
```

When I try to add this statements to the scripts section in my package.json as:

```
"lint": "eslint src/**/*.js",
```

It does run and give the correct output but then crashes. I am guessing it has to do with the quotation marks that are there if I do not run it as a package.json script.

How can I add a script to my package.json that runs eslint for all JavaScript files in my src/ directory?

Comment: Around the path.

Answer (score 3):

Just use single quotes:

```
"lint": "eslint 'src/**/*.js'"
```

Comment: This fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

After further researching (using every search in Google I could think off), it turns out this is the normal behavior of ESLint when ran as a script from npm: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7933

Comment: npm run lint -s displays the linter output and silences the npm output.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
"lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc ./src/"
```

Comment: Keeps throwing an error. First that it could not fin .eslintrc (had to put .js) behind it. And after that it crashes the same like what I tried already. Wierd thing is that it only crashes if an error is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this pattern to run on the specific file extensions

```
"lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"" // default config file .eslintrc.js or .eslintrc.json
```

If you want to use a specific **config** file then use the following pattern

```
"lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{ts,tsx,jsx}\" --config ./.eslintrc.ui.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to run lint and to fix the linting issue automatically.

```
"lint": "eslint 'src/**/*.js'"
"lintfix": "eslint 'src/**/*.js' --fix"
```